# Tkinter Pyinstaller not loading main program

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have some tkinter GUI code, which works fine when booting locally in VS Code.  But when I use Pyinstaller to create an .exe the code below works ok, but after logging in sucessfully the code below call my main program class, which fails to load.  It just creates my screen, in the right geometery with the background colour, but not none of my widgets on it.

```
from config import *
import base64
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
from attribution_tool_main_program_class import main_program
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys
from sql_uploader import azure_sql_connector
from tkinter import Tk,Label,Canvas,Entry,Button, messagebox, Toplevel,mainloop

class login_screen_class():

    def __init__(self):

        self.df  = azure_sql_connector('opr_dev').read_table('SELECT * FROM [dbo].[attribution_username_file]')
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.withdraw()
        self.login_screen = Toplevel(self.root)
        self.login_screen.title("Attribution Tool - Login")
        self.login_screen.geometry("1920x1080")
        train_icon = self.resource_path('train.ico')
        self.login_screen.iconbitmap(train_icon)
        background_image=self.resource_path('background_image_2.png')
        self.my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(background_image))
        my_label = Label(self.login_screen,image=self.my_img)
        my_label.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky='N')
        my_canvas1 = Canvas(self.login_screen,bg = "#75787B")
        my_canvas1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=200,pady=200)
 
        font= "Helvetica, 16"

        user_Name = Label(my_canvas1,text="Username",bg = "#75787B", fg="white",font=font)
        user_Name.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2,pady=10,padx=10,sticky='N')
        self.username_entry = Entry(my_canvas1,width =30,bg = "#75787B",font=font,foreground='white')
        self.username_entry.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10)
        
        password_name = Label(my_canvas1,text="Password",bg = "#75787B", fg="white",font=font,borderwidth=0)
        password_name.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=2,pady=10,padx=10)
        self.password_entry = Entry(my_canvas1,width =30,bg = "#75787B",font=font,foreground='white',show='*')
        self.password_entry.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=10)

        login_image=self.resource_path('login-button-png-7.png')
        my_img_login = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(login_image))
        sign_in_button = Button(my_canvas1,image=my_img_login, command = lambda: self.username_password_check(), borderwidth=0)
        sign_in_button.grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan=2, pady=10, padx=10)
        self.login_screen.bind_all("<Return>",self.username_password_check)
        mainloop()
    
    def resource_path(self,relative_path):
        try:
            base_path = sys._MEIPASS
        except Exception:
            base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

        return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

    def username_password_check(self,event=None):

        self.username = self.username_entry.get().lower()
        password=self.password_entry.get()
        if self.username =="":
            messagebox.showerror("No username entered", "Please enter a valid username to login to Attribution Tool")
        elif password =="":
            messagebox.showerror("No password entered", "Please enter a valid password to login to Attribution Tool")

        login_list =  self.df.values.tolist()
        for record in login_list:
            if record[0].lower() ==self.username:
                if base64.b64decode(record[1]).decode("utf-8") == password:
                    self.login_screen.withdraw()
                    main_program((self.username).capitalize(),self.root)  
                else:        
                    messagebox.showerror("Login Error", "The details you have entered are invalid")
                    break

if __name__ == '__main__':

    login_screen_class()
```

The command below is the command I am using to export the file to a .exe

```
pyinstaller --name Attribution_tool --onefile --windowed --icon=Train.ico --add-data "login-button-png-7.png;." --add-data "background_image_2.png;." --add-data "train.ico;." Attribution_tool_v19.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my pyinstaller which fixed the issue!